# module 'skimage.data' has no attribute 'imread'

Tags: python, scikit-image, imread

```
import skimage 
image = skimage.data.imread("my_image.png")
```

I used this code to read an image, but I got an error as "skimage.data" has no attribute "imread".
My skimage version is 0.18.1. What has to be changed in this to read an image?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error is straightforward. You try to call the imread function in the data module, but there is no such function in this module. Call

```
skimage.io.imread('blah.png')
```

instead.

Comment: This did not work as well, then I changed the import statement to "import skimage.io". This resolved the issue.